# Can't tweet on twitter by using supabase user access token

Tags: twitter, oauth, sveltekit, supabase, twitter-api-v2

I am using supabase/auth-helpers with sveltekit and using Twitter OAuth, and the sign up and login are working just fine.

I am using the twitter-api-v2 package, and it states that I can use access token as bearer token like so:

```
const client = new TwitterApi(MY_BEARER_TOKEN);
```

Here is my code:

```
import { variables } from '$lib/variables';
import { supabaseServerClient, withApiAuth } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit';
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';

export const GET: RequestHandler<any> = async ({ locals }) =>
    withApiAuth(
        {
            redirectTo: '/',
            user: locals.user
        },
        async () => {
            const loggedClient = new TwitterApi(locals.accessToken!, {
                clientId: variables.twitter_oauth_client_id,
                clientSecret: variables.twitter_oauth_secret
            } as any);
            const profile = await loggedClient.v2.me();

            return {
                body: {
                    data: profile as any
                }
            };
        }
    );
```

However, I am getting error 403 and sometimes 401. The error output reads:

```
Request failed with code 401
```

Here is a link to twitter api response codes: https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error message not just the error code

Comment: To use Supabase Auth, you'll need to use Twitter Auth v1 and request for elevated access.